# Не отрабатывает контроллер(метод DELETE)

Tags: ajax, laravel

Не удаляет данные из таблицы

Шаблон

```
 @extends('master')
@section('content')
    @include('_partial.errors')
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Add new
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <label class="">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name_ajax" class="form-control">
                    <label class="">Parent_id</label>
                    <input type="text" name="parent_id" id="parent_ajax" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addNew">Add New</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <div class=" table-responsive">

        <table class="table table-hover " id="table_result">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Parent_id</th>
                <th>Show Edit Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>


            <tbody>
            @foreach($items as $item)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{$item->id}}</th>
                    <th>{{$item->name}}</th>
                    <th>{{$item->parent_id}}</th>

                    <th>
                        <form >
                            @csrf
                            @method('delete')
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$item->id}}">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-success delete_ajax send">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </th>
                    {{--<th>--}}
                        {{--<a href="/ajax" class="btn btn-success btn-block ">Send Ajax</a>--}}
                    {{--</th>--}}
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <p><b></b>
    </p>
@endsection
```

Контроллер

```
public function delete($id)
    {
        $item = Test::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        return \response()->json('Item deleted');
    }
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('.delete_ajax').click(function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/delete',
            data: {id: 35},
            success: function () {
                console.log('Ok')
            },
            error:function () {
                console.log('No')
            }


        })

    })
})
```

Route

```
Route::delete ( '/delete', 'MainController@delete' );
```

Comment: какие ошибки в хроме в Панели разработчика на владке Network для запроса?

Comment: Никаких ошибок не выдает и не удаляет. В панели разработчика все 200-е ответы. Попробовал REST-сlient PHPStorm. Там выдал 419 ошибку. Везде пишут , что она означает отсутствие токена, хотя в параметрах передал его и id. Какие будут идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не передаёте `id` для удаления в роуте или не используете переданные данные из тела запроса.

В этом варианте извлекаем данные из тела запроса

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    $item = Test::findOrFail($request->input('id'))->delete();
    return \response()->json('Item deleted');
}
```

В этом варианте делаем всё проще. Передаём `id` как параметр роута. Автоматически будет найдена модель, если есть.

```
Route::delete ( '/delete/{test}', 'MainController@delete' );

public function delete(Test $test)
{
    $test->delete();
}
```

В аяксе

```
   let id = 35;
   ...
   url: '/delete/' + id,
```

Ну а ещё можно использовать [ресурсы](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) в роутах

```
Route::resource('/test', 'MainController');
```

Рекомендую пройти курсы (есть русские субтитры) - https://youtu.be/E7FQEutaCiQ

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Помогло!!!!!!!

Comment: @yuralucky в таком случае, примите ответ